# Error attempting to initialize Mono for Android Xamarin extension

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2012, mono, xamarin

So basically, when I try to open an Android project in Visual Studio 2012 (Xamarin extension), VS crashes and I get the following error

> There was an error attempting to initialize the Mono for Android extension

When I click "More Details" link, I get the following stack trace:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Mono.Debugging.Soft.ICustomLogger' from assembly 'Mono.Debugging.Soft, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5e9ce85b0923c84f'.
>
> at Mono.VisualStudio.Extension.TastyPackage.Initialize()
>
> at Mono.Android.VisualStudio.MonoAndroidPackage.Initialize()

It's driving me insane, especially because yesterday when I first cleanly installed the Xamarin package, everything was working just fine. I updated today to a newer version (because the emulator was running some old Android version) and then this problem showed up. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Mono several times, tried several versions, updated the Android SDK, fixed the AndroidSdkDirectory value in the Mono Windows registries with no success. The ActivityLog.xml shows the exception highlighted above without any extra information, so I'm pretty stuck. Any ideas?

Some screnshots:

[image: I cannot load a project or even access Mono settings in VS options]

[image: The logged error being thrown]

Comment: I feel your pain, meanwhile I'd suggest you switch to Xamarin studio, it usually works better.

Comment: Yeah, but that would be sort of a compromise as I have a lot of useful stuff in VS such as ReSharper which are not available for the Xamarin Studio. Thanks for the suggestion though, at least their studio seems to be working